# Create data model in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

The below code is working but unfortunately it is not giving the right results. I need data model pivot table instead it shows normal pivot table.

```
Sub CreateTwoDataModelPivotTablesInSameSheet()
    
        ' Set worksheets
        Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
        Dim wsProcessedData As Worksheet
        Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
        Set wsProcessedData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processed Data")
    
        ' Refresh data used in pivot tables (optional)
        ' wsProcessedData.UsedRange.Refresh
    
        ' Clear existing PivotTables
        On Error Resume Next
        wsSummary.PivotTables.ClearAll
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        ' Enable Data Model for the entire workbook
        ThisWorkbook.Model.Initialize
    
        ' Create PivotCache objects
        Dim pc1 As PivotCache, pc2 As PivotCache
        Set pc1 = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wsProcessedData.UsedRange)
        Set pc2 = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wsProcessedData.UsedRange)
    
        ' Calculate starting row for the second table
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 10
    
        ' Create first PivotTable
        Dim pt1 As PivotTable
        Set pt1 = pc1.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsSummary.Cells(60, 2), TableName:="PivotTable1")
    
        ' Set PivotTable1 fields and configurations
        With pt1.PivotFields("Preparer")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
        End With
     
        With pt1.PivotFields("Reviewer")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
        End With
        
        With pt1.PivotFields("Year & Month")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
        End With
        
        With pt1.PivotFields("Error Rate")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
        End With
        
        With pt1.PivotFields("Major Error")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Name = "Major Error"
        End With
        
        With pt1.PivotFields("Check Number")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlCount
            .Function = xlDistinctCount
            .Calculation = xlPercentOfColumn ' Use xlDistinctCount to get the distinct count
        .NumberFormat = "0%"  ' Display as a percentage
            .Name = "%"
        End With
        ' ... (other field settings)
    
        With pt1.PivotFields("Check Number")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlCount
            .Calculation = xlPercentOfColumn
            .NumberFormat = "0%"
            .Name = "% of Check Number"
        End With
    
        ' Set style and refresh
        pt1.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleDark10"
        pt1.RefreshTable
    
        ' Manually add PivotTable1 to Data Model
        pt1.CacheIndex = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModel.Tables.Count + 1
    
        ' Create second PivotTable
        Dim pt2 As PivotTable
        Set pt2 = pc2.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsSummary.Rows(lastRow + 1).Offset(-1, 4), TableName:="PivotTable2")
    
        ' Set PivotTable2 fields and configurations
        With pt2.PivotFields("Preparer")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
        End With
    
        ' ... (other field settings)
    
        With pt2.PivotFields("Check Number")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlCount
            .Calculation = xlPercentOfColumn
            .NumberFormat = "0%"
            .Name = "% of Check Number"
        End With
    
        ' Set style and refresh
        pt2.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16"
        pt2.RefreshTable
    
        ' Manually add PivotTable2 to Data Model
        pt2.CacheIndex = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModel.Tables.Count + 1
    
        ' Set column widths (optional)
        wsSummary.Range("B:C").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20
        wsSummary.Range("F:G").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20
    End Sub
```

It is creating normal pivot instead of data model pivot table, can someone please help on the same. I have been trying from more than a month now not able to find right solution.
Is there any way to handle this any alternative solution.

Comment: Is anything in that code supposed to establish relationships between tables?

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* The code should be tested on a new workbook. Running the code multiple times may result in errors due to duplicated names of tables, queries, etc. Additional code is required to detect and remove any unnecessary objects in the workbook.

Steps to create PowerPivot table :

- Add a table (ListObject)
- Add a query
- Add a connection
- Add a PowerPivot table
- Update PowerPivot layout

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePPT()
    Dim objPP As PivotTable, sForm As String
    Dim sDataFld As String, sConn As String
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Const QUERY_NAME = "QueryTable1"
    Const TABLE_NAME = "DataTable"
    ' Add Table
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TABLE_NAME
    ' Add Query
    sForm = "let" & vbCrLf & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""@@""]}[Content]," _
        & vbCrLf & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Name"", type text}, " & _
        "{""Sales"", type number}})" & vbCrLf & "in" & vbCrLf & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=TABLE_NAME, Formula:=Replace(sForm, "@@", TABLE_NAME)
    ' Add Connection
    sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=@@;Extended Properties="
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _
            Name:=QUERY_NAME, _
            Description:="Connection to the table query in the workbook.", _
            ConnectionString:=Replace(sConn, "@@", TABLE_NAME), _
            CommandText:="""" & TABLE_NAME & """", _
            lCmdtype:=6, _
            CreateModelConnection:=True, _
            ImportRelationships:=False
   ' Add PowerPivot
    Set objPP = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
            ActiveWorkbook.Connections(QUERY_NAME)).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range("D1"))
    With objPP.CubeFields("[" & TABLE_NAME & "].[Name]")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    sDataFld = "Sum of Sales"
    objPP.CubeFields.GetMeasure "[" & TABLE_NAME & "].[Sales]", xlSum, sDataFld
    objPP.AddDataField objPP.CubeFields("[Measures].[" & sDataFld & "]"), sDataFld
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> Parameter `CreateModelConnection` specifies whether to create a connection to the PowerPivot model.

> [Connections.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connections.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm776079)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Sample data

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Sales |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A3 | 3 |
| A1 | 4 |
| A2 | 5 |
| A3 | 6 |
| A1 | 7 |
| A2 | 8 |
| A3 | 9 |
| A1 | 10 |